# Sort and Table a Sentence by Word Lengths

Tags: code-golf, string, sorting

In as few bytes as possible, sort the input, *a delimited string OR list/vector/array of words, words contain printable ASCII except space (ASCII values 33-126)* into a numbered list, table, or something resembling a table, by length.

Table rules are as follows:

- Order is mandatory, direction is optional, either labelled rows from shortest to longest or vice versa,
- Formatting is not the challenge. So as long as the output is some form of numerically labelled rows of words, a numbered list, or a list of lists, or similar output, then it is a satisfactory answer.
- including/excluding gaps (NA values, see below examples for both methods of output)
- Word case is untouched. How the word appears in input should be shown in output.

**Input 1:**

```
Code Golf and Coding Challenges Meta
```

**or**

```
("Code","Golf","and","Coding","Challenges","Meta")
```

**or similar**

**Output 1:**

```
 1. NA
 2. NA
 3. and
 4. Code Golf Meta
 5. NA
 6. Coding
 7. NA
 8. NA
 9. NA
 10. Challenges
```

**or**

```
3. and
4. Code Golf Meta
6. Coding
10. Challenges
```

**or**

```
[[3, ['and']], [4, ['Code', 'Golf', 'Meta']], [6, ['Coding']], [10, ['Challenges']]]
```

**Input 2:**

```
My v3ry 3xc3113nt m0th3r ju5t 53rv3d u5 nin3 pizz@5 #JusticeForPluto
```

**Output 2:**

```
1. NA
2. My u5
3. NA
4. v3ry ju5t nin3
5. NA
6. m0th3r 53rv3d pizz@5
7. NA
8. NA
9. 3xc3113nt
10. NA
11. NA
12. NA
13. NA
14. NA
15. NA
16. #JusticeForPluto
```

**or**

```
2. My u5
4. v3ry ju5t nin3
6. m0th3r 53rv3d pizz@5
9. 3xc3113nt
16. #JusticeForPluto
```

**or**

```
[[2, ['My', 'u5']], [4, ['v3ry', 'ju5t', 'nin3']], [6, ['m0th3r', '53rv3d', 'pizz@5']], [9, ['3xc3113nt']], [16, ['#JusticeForPluto']]]
```

More examples can be provided if necessary but I think this should suffice for now.
Please ask questions if you have them, this is my second attempt at a challenge. (the first failed dramatically)

Comment: In your second example, it seems that `@` is part of a word, but `.` is not, and `#` is. Could you please define what a "word" means? Thanks.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Sorry, I meant to delete that period. I'll make some edits

Comment: Can the length be in unary?

Comment: @someone I'm unfamiliar with unary outputs. I'd have to see it to confirm, but I imagine it can be a valid answer.

Answer (score 12):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
split(w<-scan(,""),nchar(w))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFNCoMwEAbQq3zoJgGFypBdF111URB6BYmCKXaUyST@XD6@J6XEbQlq9mcb/cCmqSrbsJ8HMbu1pT@RSU7Q4anriBX/h84k@CWncCSZRiQHDkzYwnW9HOpPihr89F7luyRdyw0)

`split` does the trick; results in a `list()` where the element names are the lengths and  the elements are `vectors` containing the words.

Comment: I was wondering about the best R method. I didn't even know split existed, or how it worked. That's fantastic!

Comment: @Sumner18 yes, `split` is [super nice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181029/deal-the-cards-to-the-players/181032#181032); if you're doing something that requires `split`, a transformation on each group, and an `unsplit`, then `ave` is worth trying as well.

Answer (score 8):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>12</s> 14 bytes

```
{x@=#'x@:<#'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqrrCwVZZvcLBygZI1v5PU9BQ8q1UslYqMy4CUcYVycaGhsZ5JUB2rkFJhnERkJFVagrimxoXlRmnABmlpkAiLzPPGEgVZFZVOYD4yl6lxSWZyalu@UUBOaUl@Uqa/wE)

this returns a k dictionary. lengths are key, words are value. let me know if this output format is acceptable.

in q (wrapper around the k4 dialect), we can evaluate using the k interpreter and get q output formatting:

```
q)k){x@=#:'x@:<#:'x}("Code"; "Golf"; "and"; "Coding"; "Challenges"; "Meta")
3 | ,"and"
4 | ("Meta";"Golf";"Code")
6 | ,"Coding"
10| ,"Challenges"
```

note the extra colons, which aren't required for "eached" monads in the ngn implementation

Comment: Definitely an interesting output format. If this output is functional as a dictionary, and could be used, say, as input to some other program, then I would say it is acceptable.

Comment: @Sumner18 oh yeah, it's functionally a dictionary. see [here](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqrrCwVZZvcLByq6i9n@RVZqChpJzfkqqkrWCknt@ThqITsxLAVFA4cy8dDArIzEnJzUvPbUYxPNNLUlU0rTmKlIwVjD5DwA), where we assign the dict to r, then use key juxtaposition to return the corresponding values

Comment: @scrawl did you mean `{x@=#'x@:<#'x}`?

Comment: @ngn, yes. i am constantly getting ahead of myself and not testing robustness

Comment: that being said, my initial submission was pretty wrong in 2 big ways. it wasn't just missing edge cases

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Input as an array of words, output as a 2D-array.

```
üÊËiDÎÊ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=/MrLaUTOyg&input=WyJDb2RlIiwiR29sZiIsImFuZCIsIkNvZGluZyIsIkNoYWxsZW5nZXMiLCJNZXRhIl0KLVE)

```
üÊËiDÎÊ     :Implicit input of array
ü           :Group and sort by
 Ê          :  Length
  Ë         :Map each sub-array D
   i        :  Prepend
    DÎÊ     :    Length of first element of D
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 19 bytes

```perl6
*.classify(*.chars)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrRCsIgGIbh813FB0FUB6MhdhJBMCgIBt2CTN0Mp@NXV@7mbWfvA@@syF7KlLHXuKGc6t6KEIzOhy1HQeFYrlUQGfXXkwz1tmlPsMapUFovFZ7eaggnscm4Ae0orFVuUAGdiqLqMhZGGezXs6ZhLmI6x5ERPolHcEYLk0gczjiG2azrnWP3SiGaXj08vW2K/g8)

Pretty much does exactly as asked.

```perl6
*.classify(       )  # Classify the list
           *.chars   # By number of characters
```

Comment: I've heard of Perl's godlike ability to handle strings and regular expressions. I would expect nothing less of it.

Comment: @Sumner18 You're probably thinking of Perl 5 (though Perl 6 (now known as Raku) is pretty good at it too)

Answer (score 6):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 18 bytes

```powershell
$args|group Length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJdT8IwFH3fr2i0WBaHASsmPpAsMZHEgPHdGLJs3Ycp7Ww7QGC/HdtubA6Ifdi9t@f03HNvlvM1ETIllB5gPNkdYCASuU8EL3IwIyxR6aF0HL/vAH28Kpjj99Ezjwjy0JTTWIeARfqr7zKWmCQNKNXvidTFnKgAuV77eNek5iCMJlrPKLhd4MEC3UaVWJf3eOSZ5ifYaFiBraGWUNrMvTDc/Ee3WmFhAt6EeDTCTOl8OVQpFjr5KsamHmOxwmbyYqw/LGNYhzzbbn1TX78WUmUheeHinRaK/7eEe2vT9tVaFxdR@6lb22YXF9GYbNzVjk7YT5bdjne6Oa12PsLZ8lywBz1QTQPXXETSA5BschIqEoEJgIsKEkQWVOmLGxgD3xIdi/RraN9rV9IIzDJGjMix/oCLu7dgST4bKkK3@m5qf9lBSL7BVefxlSWWLhgwrkLOVJAxCWAcUEn@GnPKwy8)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>147</strike> 129 bytes

Thanks to girobuz and ceilingcat for the suggestions.

This routine first finds the maximum string length of an input array of strings, then prints the words by length in reverse.

```c
m,*t;f(int**s){for(t=s;*s;m=fmax(m,strlen(*s++)+1));for(;--m;)for(printf("\n%d",m),s=t;*s;)printf(" %s"+3*(strlen(*s++)!=m),*s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHLSgMxFN3PV8SUQpJJxRK6iiOCoCCtuHFVuwiZV2SSKUmm1Jb5dccboaBucs85uY@TG71otJ4my1mUNTEuMhboue49iUWQLEhb1FYdieUh@q5yhIU8p/mSUpmS5GJhJU1o76G4JvjdzUvMLeWhiKmeXi7QPOBcMPK7z1UBiTBQjtPMON0NZYVuQyxNf93eZRkUIquMS76Q8o3mSLfKI8aAHCg6Z@gihO2uSBQhkhS23dEzfujLCnP81Hc1BOXAWNKMaxJoVQdGmioA2VRRYf7ytl6P/H@XzSckHIRPQRy1WC6Fi4DtTWyFB/AxrBJfCX8QacSwgsMZJyDszel0n/jseQjR6Oqx96/dEPs/0xIEMHJ4CUuLz4D97BfBv6D9EAPBmFJUExZhbzIbpy9dd6oJ06Kz3w)

Comment: [143 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVFNSwMxFLzvr4gphSSbFUvoxbhVEBSkihdPpYcl@ylJtiTZqi37111fhIp6yZsZXua9TFTWKDVNRtbE88A17WxgzHPGgjzWvSMh95J5aXKz0tfmUlOd@@B0ZQnzaUrThYxdMsuM3A3BE4wpjcrOgVNN8LzE3FDu8xBt6ElGc49Twchvr7McGpmncpxmnVV6KCt05UPZ9eftKkngIjJFZ0kEhWsUR6otHGIMyJ6iY4JOgt9s80gRIlFhmy094tu@rDDH972uoRQWFotaZ5sI2kLDIk3lgTxWocD86WW9Hvl/l8cPaNgLF4t4V2KxEDYANhehFQ7A67CMfCncXsQRwxIO21kBZdcdDjeRzx4GHzpV3fXuWQ@h/zMtQgAjh5ewmH8C7DtlBL@CfmJGNWEBcpPJOH2qWheNn7K3Lw)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 50 bytes

Input as an array of words, output as an object where the keys are the word lengths and the values are arrays of words.

```
a=>a.map(w=>o[l=w.length]=[...o[l]||[],w],o={})&&o
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##FYw9DsMgDEbvwhCBRLmBs3To1BMgBisBksrFUYnC0PTs1Fm@nze8Fx5Yp8@67bfCc@wJOsKI7o2bbjCyJ2iOYsn7EsA754SE8/TBtmAZvj8zDNwnLpUpOuKsk/bqLipl1YMpSWGZJYWtJV9jQbqMscp5xh1VMKb/AQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 37 bytes

```
S` 
.+
$.& $&
O#`
r`(?<=\1.+)¶(.+ )
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/OEGBS0@bS0VPTUFFjctfOYGrKEHD3sY2xlBPW/PQNg09bQVNLoX//53zU1IV3PNz0hQS81IUgLzMvHQF54zEnJzUvPTUYgXf1JJEAA) Explanation:

```
S`
```

Split the input on spaces.

```
.+
$.& $&
```

Precede each word by its length.

```
O#`
```

Sort numerically.

```
r`(?<=\1.+)¶(.+ )
```

If two lines start with the same length, delete the newline and the length.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>76</s> <s>74</s> 72 bytes

```python
lambda a:sorted((l,[d for d in a if len(d)==l])for l in set(map(len,a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYs9DsMgDIWvYjEZialjJaYOnXqCtoMrmwTJAURYenpilvf36bX/2Gu5zRQ/U@n4MQHdz9qHMKKGN0OqHRhyAYKcQKUg@xj16xfQBU4ZeFBDY4G897P1XAYkRPeoLC64Z9VkRoVNbctlW2Entc8mp5WXDHL2vQA)

Comment: Can squeeze a couple more bytes with set unpacking in python 3 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYs9DsIwDIWvYmWyUTY2pEwMTJwAGIyctJHcJEqzIMTZg7u8v0@vfcZay3mm8JzK21sY@LLXPqIgqn8IpNpBIBdgyAk0FhQKQV90ADXwPW3c0IBn@tFsPZeBCdFdq0Tn3a1qMuMiprblshxhZbXPEncr9zjYEdH8Aw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>9</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
€gêεùy‚
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@Grimy*.

Outputs a list of lists from lowest to highest, with the label at the right side instead of left. I.e. `[[["and"],3],[["Code","Golf","Meta"],4],[["Coding"],6],[["Challenges"],10]]`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdOa9MOrzm09vLPyUcOs//@jlZzzU1KVdJTc83PSgFRiXgqQBIpl5qWDGBmJOTmpeempxUCOb2pJolIsAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6nDpeRfWgLjHVr5/1HTmvTDq85tPbSu@PDOykcNs/7X6hzaZv8/OlrJOT8lVUlHyT0/Jw1IJealAEmgWGZeOoiRkZiTk5qXnloM5PimliQqxeooRCv5VgK5ZcZFIMq4ItnY0NA4rwTIzjUoyTAuAjKySk1BfFPjojJjkIGlpkAiLzPPGEgVZFZVOYD4yl6lxSWZyalu@UUBOaUl@UqxsQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
€g       # Get the length of each string in the (implicit) input-list
  ê      # Sort and uniquify this list of lengths
   ε     # Map each length `y` to:
    ù    #  Keep strings from the (implicit) input-list equal to this length
     y‚  #  And pair it with the current length `y`
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: `é.γg}` => `€gêù` for -1. EDIT: actually [here's 7](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdOa9MOrzm09vLPyUcOs//@jlZzzU1KVdJTc83PSgFRiXgqQBIpl5qWDGBmJOTmpeempxUCOb2pJolIsAA).

Comment: @Grimmy Thanks. Now the grouped by `.γ` builtin looks even more useless than I already thought.. xD

Comment: Turns out there was actually a group-by built-in all this time: `.¡` (incorrectly documented as sort-by). It doesn't
save any bytes here (`ù` is more appropriate anyway), but it dramatically
improved [this old answer of
mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/186409/group-integers-by-originality/186413#186413).

Comment: @Grimmy Oh, that's good to know. Never knew we had one. Did you discovered this in the source code? Maybe tag _@Mr.Xcoder_ somewhere so he could change the wiki for it?

Comment: I discovered this because I wanted to use split-by for [another challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196003/convert-complex-chinese-numbers-into-arabic-numbers), but it didn’t behave like I thought it would, so I investigated it.

Answer (score 4):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 53 bytes

```
map({l:length,s:.})|group_by(.l)|.[]|[.[0].l,[.[].s]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYdNC4MgGID/i7sUiBQvXjrttMNg0F1kbC3KMHV@xGrutzu9PB/LO6X1Yaqv7OSoJj9j15FfHSerg7k/94rIOhLGIyOs4UTibE4c5ykxdNsRRhvYIvgM0LagfO618TPYHEug5SnYDV45As1QQkGWEcdxLn@6BufFMF607WXwGvE/)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first post.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>22</s> 28 bytes

```ruby
->w{w.group_by(&:size).sort}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1668ulwvvSi/tCA@qVJDzao4sypVU684v6ik9n@BQlp0tJJzfkqqko6Se35OGpBKzEsBkkCxzLx0ECMjMScnNS89tRjI8U0tSVSKjf0PAA)

Comment: This output is not ordered shortest to longest words.

Comment: Sorry, now it is.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 bytes

```apl
(⍋⊃¨⊂)≢¨{⊂⍺⍵}⌸⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X@NRb/ejruZDKx51NWk@6lx0aEU1kPWod9ej3q21j3p2POpa9D/tUduER719j/qmevqD1K43ftQ2EcgLDnIGkiEensH/0xTUnfNTUtUV1N3zc9KAVGJeijpYLDMvHcTISMzJSc1LTy0GcnxTSxLVAQ)

APL is not particularly good at simply sorting.

#### How it works

```apl
(⍋⊃¨⊂)≢¨{⊂⍺⍵}⌸⊢
      ≢¨     ⌸⊢  Group the arg's elements by their lengths
        {⊂⍺⍵}    Wrap each list of items, paired with the length
(⍋⊃¨⊂)           Idiom for sorting:
 ⍋               Grade up; gives indexes that will make the array sorted
  ⊃¨⊂            Map the indexes to the items
```

Comment: You could save 1 with `(⍋⊃¨⊂)≢¨(⊂,)⌸⊢` or [go Extended](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HH8kediw6teNTV9Kh3ic6jnh2Puhb9T3vUNuFRb9@jvqme/o@6mg@tN37UNhHICw5yBpIhHp7B/9MU1J3zU1LVFdTd83PSgFRiXoo6WCwzLx3EyEjMyUnNS08tBnJ8U0sS1QE "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online"): `∧≢¨⊂⍤,⌸⊢`

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>31</s> <s>27</s> 23 bytes

Takes input as a newline-separated list of words (I haven't noticed that's allowed at first).

```
.+
$.& $&
N`
D`\d+
¶
```

I'll add the explanation later (for now, the previous revision's explanation without the first line works perfectly).
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS0VPTUFFjcsvgcslISZFm@vQNgUuhf//A4ry04sSc3Mz89K5AkqrqnJSi7kS81K4nPNTUrnc83PSYDyQAueMxJyc1Lz01GIA)

Comment: Is this what you were referring to as unary output? It looks okay to me.

Comment: @Sumner18 This is definitely not unary output :) I was planning to use it in the Retina answer I was planning to create, but decimal turned out to be shorter (in unary, the lengths would be basically runs of `#` characters instead of numbers)

Comment: That's what I thought, I guess I was just confused. My reasoning is that if a unary output could be a useful input in some other program, or if one could reason why unary labelling is valid/useful, then I believe it would be a satisfactory response.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <del>59</del> 56 bytes

```hs
l=length
f s=[(n,[x|x<-s,l x==n])|n<-[1..maximum$l<$>s]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY3NasMwEITveQqh5pCAY2qEb1YJFFooGHIXpohEjtWs1kY/QQl5d3d1mZlvYXYmHW4GYHXaIpPM6aX/ZbvFW4ysZuOeqQ1T/HO@GF7x7xlGMo0XUrpZvJYwaQCDVxMIehM1H6pS6h/Ed@GLiXwWTSMwUnbvcRKewl9qC7fC30X5mFoStCjIFvt8Hgu//aQQ7dl8zf4EKc58GFaQZS9Om5EFqXZYqfzK3SFUwLKUOOxf2B1UU9dOZ@uS20K3/QhUXP8B)

- -3 bytes by using a list comprehension instead of a lambda, thanks to [79037662](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/195807/sort-and-table-a-sentence-by-word-lengths/195892?noredirect=1#comment466596_195892)

Comment: This seems to work for 56 bytes, list comprehension is usually shorter than mapping with a lambda: https://tio.run/##FY3NasMwEITveQqh5pCAY2qEb1YJFFooGHIXpohEjtWs1kY/QQl5d3d1mZlvYXYmHW4GYHXaIpPM6aX/ZbvFW4ysZuOeqQ1T/HO@GF7x7xlGMo0XUrpZvJYwaQCDVxMIehM1H6pS6h/Ed@GLiXwWTSMwUnbvcRKewl9qC7fC30X5mFoStCjIFvt8Hgu//aQQ7dl8zf4EKc58GFaQZS9Om5EFqXZYqfzK3SFUwLKUOOxf2B1UU9dOZ@uS20K3/QhUXP8B

Comment: @79037662 Thanks, applied.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
lᵍ{hl}ᶻ¹o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfBCoIwGADgV/lZ14JqeK1AKAiE7tFh6dLF2mJumoqHPBQdgh6li4F1603mi1jf7dsq4kcZl@G4K1IEgwmgdGqba1ud28uzrSr7vpW2fnTc1vci4qV9fb6N7Lo1cmVAYSH5DogI4D8mQnAjwjkVIY3Bo5qgPvIySLDKAJ98PBphoeEw1BFWsDeOBgerBAdgHBBMYDiyPJ850FuaWDOfzqVacaMl2vwA)

Takes input as a list of words (the testing header converts from space-separated for convenience). Output is as a list of pairs `[length,words]`, sorted in ascending order of length. Two alternative solutions of the same length, `lᵒlᵍ{hl}ᶻ` and `lᵍ{hl}ᶻtᵒ`, output pairs reversed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 8 bytes

```
ẈẈḢ,Ɗƙ⁸Ṣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrg4Q2rFI51jXsZmPGnc83Lno/@H2o5Me7pzx/7@Sc35KqpKOknt@ThqQSsxLAZJAscy8dBAjIzEnJzUvPbUYyPFNLUlUAgA)

A monadic link which takes a list of Jelly strings and returns a list of lists where the first member of each list is the length and the second is a list of Jelly strings of that length. Plus 2 bytes now it’s been clarified that ordering of the list is mandatory.

Comment: I suppose I should clarify. Ordering the list is mandatory, direction is optional.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
m+lhdd.gl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1c7JyMlRS895/9/DSXn/JRUJR0l9/ycNCCVmJcCJIFimXnpIEZGYk5Oal56ajGQ45takqikCQA)

Port of [@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195808/90146)'s answer, so I cant really take credit for this (lol)

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

```
m+dfqdlTQSleol
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1c7Ja0wJSckMDgnNT/n/38NJef8lFQlHSX3/Jw0IJWYlwIkgWKZeekgRkZiTk5qXnpqMZDjm1qSqKQJAA)

Saves a few bytes by mapping a filtered list to each number in a 1-indexed range. This only saves 2 bytes due to the fact that the last two bytes can be implicit (would be `m+dfqdlTQSleolNQ` otherwise)

### How it works

```
m+dfqdlTQSleol
m              - Map
 +d            - The sum of the element and...
   fqdlTQ      - The filtered input where each element of the input is length d        
         Sl    - To the range [1, length]
           eol - of the last element of the ordered list by key=length
               - Print implicitly
```

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 16 bytes

```
FkSleolNQkfqklTQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3y07OCc1P8cvMDutMDsnJPD/fw0l5/yUVCUdJff8nDQglZiXAiSBYpl56SBGRmJOTmpeemoxkOObWpKopAkA)

16 bytes seems a bit high for a challenge like this but oh well. Would be 14 bytes but it looks like the last 2 bytes cant be implicit due to how filter works in pyth

### How it works

```
FkSleolNQkfqklTQ
Fk                 - For k in...
  Sl               - The range [1, length]
    eolN           - Of the last element of the sorted list by key=length
        Q          - Of the input
         k         - Print k
          fqklT    - Filter by key k == length...
               Q   - The input (prints implicitly)
```

Sorry if this answer is too long, I can cut it a bit if needed

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>63</s> 53 bytes

```powershell
$a=@{};$args|%{$a[$_.length]+=" $_"};$a|% *or|sort N*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXR1qG61lolsSi9uEa1WiUxWiVeLyc1L70kI1bbVklBJV4JJFujqqCVX1RTnF9UouCn9f//f3Xn/JRU9f/q7vk5aUAqMS9FHSyWmZcOYmQk5oAMSS0GcnxTSxLVAQ)

*(-10 bytes thanks to mazzy)*

Takes arguments via [splatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6), which on TIO manifests as separate command-line arguments.

We first construct an empty hashtable `$a`, then loop through the input arguments. Each item is tacked onto `$a` in the appropriate `$_.length` slot. Then comes the lengthy `.GetEnumerator()` followed by a `sort` to get the hashtable to print out in order. That's left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-040n`), <s>45</s>, <s>40</s>, 34 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to Xcali

```perl
$a[y///c].=" $_"}{say$b++,$_ for@a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lMbpSX18/OVbPVklBJV6ptro4sVIlSVtbRyVeIS2/yCHx/3/n/JRUBff8nDSFxLwUBSAvMy9dwTkjMScnNS89tVjBN7Uk8V9@QUlmfl7xf10DE4O8nP@6vqZ6BoYA)

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gtDjDoVolMbpSX18/ObZWRyW@tro4sVIlSVtbR0nBQSVeKS2/yCHx/3/n/JRULvf8nDSuxLwULiAvMy@dyzkjMScnNS89tZjLN7Uk8V9@QUlmfl7xf928nP@6vqZ6BoYA "Perl 5 – Try It Online") if 0 can be included as an entry.  Either way, using `\n` as a delimiter can save a byte or two.

Comment: or adding `-040n` option to set space as record delimiter

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
üÊ®uZÎl
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=/MqudVrObA&input=WyJDb2RlIiwiR29sZiIsImFuZCIsIkNvZGluZyIsIkNoYWxsZW5nZXMiLCJNZXRhIl0KLVE)

```
üÊ®uZÎl // input as array of words
üÊ // group by length
  ® // for each group
   uZÎl // append length of 1st word
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 62 bytes

```php
for(;$w=$argv[++$i];ksort($a))$a[strlen($w)][]=$w;print_r($a);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCoAgEAA/swelJ1h08NCpF4jEQqaSqKySz9/qMjAMU0Plea0fr0JCwVgAyT9mmiBadbdCXQBKCWhap@SygCGtsQsMVSnmftDfFTPrcjreSroY8/lbzJ51wPRd3jXeXccX)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 22 bytes

-2 bytes thaks to FrownyFrog

If the output can be a table with some empty boxes:

```
[:/:~#@>(,~#&.>@{.)/.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VctNC4IwAIfxu5/iT0JLsKkML0IiCAaREF2jg@h8w7bQTdLAr25eOzyH3@Fp1x0lJU4BCGy4CLaOFPH9mqyPwAkWMwoP9mLuaRh9qeXQ52oZMHheS5TItQKJZcFxll2JTBTY1IgKcZ11HRcVH5BylZG/I50wsn4C@@TM85hQeLmqZj1a7Sv4rB9ZAe1DNILh3cxz5MO86EE1OU9kf@u0kmT9AQ)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 24 bytes

```
/:~@(#@><@(#@>@{.;])/.])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYvNCoJAAAbvPsVHHjah/GHxYj8IgkEkRPcOsq66Yruhu5IGvbpJtw4zMIdp5pVLShwiEGzgI1rYukhul3T2ok@8tuPj/uf47e7ujufendmxYHFWK5RgRoMkquA4qbZELgssJWSFpM7blsuK98i4zsnfkY0YaDeCvhgNAio1Hr6uaYfGhBoh7QZawISQQlI8xTTFIeyz6bVgPFXdtTVakfkL)

Just made it work - no doubt it can be golfed further.

Comment: The output from J is beautiful. Does it always look like this?

Comment: @Sumner18 It is `boxed` - J works on homogeneous arrays (vectors, tables and so on). When it is necessary to store data of different type (as it is now - numbers and lists of strings) and length, the data should be `boxed`

Comment: @Sumner18 [Here](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I18hNkbdIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFUZ0LLGyDXTg2JlPP0ACmBMz@/x8A) is some examples of boxed vs regular arrays in J. Please note the trailing spaces/zeros  of the regular arrays. The boxed versions contain no fill.

Comment: `[:/:~#@>(,~#&.>@{.)/.]` if these empty boxes are acceptable

Comment: @FrownyFrog Thank you! Maybe this format is acceptable.

Comment: Another approach with the same number of bytes: `/:~@((>;~0{#&>)/.~#&>)`

Comment: @Traws This is also nice, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <strike>30</strike> 42 bytes

Correction thanks to Value Ink

```
(s:String)=>s.split(" ").groupBy(_.length)
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/buVNQluwRumhzpeCJ1K5Qw)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, assuming the input is already in a variable (in this case `s`) is not one of our [Standard IO Methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). In addition, I notice that this doesn't print the value (it seems to require a call to `print`), meaning that this is a snippet, which doesn't conform to our rules

Comment: Thank you. Would replacing s with args[0] do the trick then? As for requiring a call to print, the runner I included displays the result without the call but not in stdout.

Comment: Also more generally, what is the standard for JVM languages here? One also needs class definitions, a main method etc. to get a 'non-snippet' so not sure what is deemed too much to exclude

Comment: Unfortunately, being a Python guy myself, I'm not to familiar with the site rules for other languages. However, if you have a look at some of the highest votes questions on [Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com), you should be able to find the defaults/rules for other languages

Comment: I believe the correct format based on [this tutorial on lambdas](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-expression-in-scala/) is `(s:String)=>s.split(" ").groupBy(_.length)`. (You don't need to include the assignment portion `val f=` by our rules.) [Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/e2Nf2TqLSLGoXD2hrWe8iQ)

Comment: I don't know Scala, but isn't `_.split(" ").groupBy(_.length)` an anonymous lambda too? In the same way as `_.length`?

Answer (score 2):

## RPL, 60+10 bytes

Let's explore more creative output formats:

```
DUP«SIZE»DOLIST SWAP 2«STR→ X ROT ^ *»DOLIST ΣLIST EXPANDMOD
```

turns the list {"Code" "Golf" "and" "Coding" "Challenges" "Meta"} into the polynomial 
Challenges·X<sup>10</sup>+Coding·X<sup>6</sup>+(Code+Golf+Meta)·X<sup>4</sup>+and·X<sup>3</sup> thanks to EXPANDMOD.

Sadly to allow exotic names like pizz@5 – just for you to know, `@` introduces comments – `STR→` must be replaced by `#5B15h SYSEVAL` adding 10 bytes to the source code, and obfuscating the call. That does however allow printable and even non printable chars, the latters only displayed as black squares but not lost. So the garbage resistant code is

```
DUP«SIZE»DOLIST SWAP 2«#5B15h SYSEVAL X ROT ^ *»DOLIST ΣLIST EXPANDMOD
```

(EXPANDMOD is present in HP50g at least. Tested with [Emu48](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.emulator.forty.eight) in 50g mode.
The code page is documented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPL_character_set#Code_page_layout)).

Answer (score 2):

## SimpleTemplate, 136 bytes

Yeah, it's a long one... The order of the output is what made it longer :/

```
{@setM 0}{@eachargv.0}{@callstrlen intoR _}{@setL.[R]L.[R],_}{@ifM is lowerR}{@setM R}{@/}{@/}{@forfrom 1toM}{@echo_}.{@echojl" " L.[_]}
```

Incredibly, it is easier (and shorter) to output that to return.

You can try it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec4bf4b3efa93c63c6c5c9f1458330da0178b6cd
(Line 974 has the words, line 976 has the golfed/ungolfed version variable)

---

**Ungolfed**:

```
{@set results}
{@set max 0}
{@each argv.0 as word}
    {@call strlen into length word}
    {@set results.[length] results.[length], word}
    {@if max is lower than length}
        {@set max length}
    {@/}
{@/}
{@for i from 1 to length}
    {@echo i}.{@echo separator " " results.[i], "\n"}
{@/}
```

Most of it should be easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

```
KeySort@*GroupBy[StringLength]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU@9CsIwEN59CombOFhCR6EoWFALhY6lQ2hTE0mTkl6KrfjsMZfF5b6f@/m4gYHgAwPZMt@f/J0vlbGQ7XNr3Hhe6gqs1M8H108QjS@DgLqvP@RiOk4OW5Ib1SMy3SEEO4xHJphSYY1PqAoOjHybZvO/UCzYmKmNSN8tTRKqAcVwBEEtspdLo5NSO9OY4FKsWmqKOMp1zaKzu7kpfMGvxpbKgcE0/wM)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 53 bytes

Takes input as a list of words. Returns an object whose keys are the lengths and whose values are the lists of corresponding words.

```javascript
a=>a.map(w=>(o[n=w.length]=o[n]||[]).push(w),o={})&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcw9DsIgFADgqxCGhpcoN6BLBydP0DC8tPwZ5BGhMljPjjh@y/fAN5btFXK9JtpNt6qjmlE@MYumZkFrUk1Gk1z1Wg3p81w1yHwULxpcSH2@ME3UN0qFopGRnLCCLyNjN4qWYdrZUEiOLR7jvzKF3U1FLkuOoQrOOAD0Hw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 107 bytes

```
func[a][m: copy#()foreach w sort a[k: length? w
unless m/:k[put m k copy[]]append m/:k w]sort/skip to[]m 2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5PS8QwEMXv/RSP7kVP6xp66UVBUBAE8RpyiMl0G5smIX@2dr98TRe8zJt5w@/NRNLbF2kumqHfhuIUl4LPPZQP6@HufvCRpBqxIPmYIfnUw5I75/EJS1OcpZQwH/uJh5IxY7qBXAgZAjl9W2ERO3xMkwnInosZj2IL0X8TBvD2xWtq0b55O1SRTtdaPePOezNKux@kVIcPyrIVzT@agjW5uisuLK5gv4qdTszVPx7yyCJ@SpfRsXhhGqWDM44hmOv1ucPhvaRsFL36@GlL9m0Nk4q2Pw)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 48 bytes

```cs
a=>a.GroupBy(k=>k.Length,v=>v).OrderBy(g=>g.Key)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/BTsJAEL33KzarhzYpjWTDCdoYiRAQotGDB@RQ26GsLLtku1uFpt9eZ6smkDiHmfd2Xua9zcpeVvJ2YmU2Ko3mslitQzK7l3YPOn0XMJpNtbIHXIy4NOGPJkkSsiFxm8ZJGnX7u6O/i5NdtABZmG1YxUkVRI86B42bIk6K6AGOQTv0KsVz8qq5gWcorTD@nytJdVEGXu0RrLGSpRIQdcJfSTRXXPr0TdKQbPxOHb2AgMw4g2tadx4NqS/khIZF0NAgCIZe450bS/gkq3VNxyoHGtKpEhscqcyx4xuecGCbCoF/ghLJEkxKGzx0EW/BJbhYvfOiqPrPbHnEOxXTbrCvjPX7TBrE@xuzZRrBhx04PmC6Yi6JHWCTXDIcB3463Tp@Nbel4RlMlH4S1igXqv0G)

-1 byte thanks to @dzaima

-43 bytes if returning the raw grouping is allowed, thanks to @someone

-18 bytes by switching to the Visual C# Interactive Compiler

Comment: I think you can simply return the results of the OrderBy.

Comment: @someone, It's kind of unclear but I'll add that as a third option too

Answer (score 1):

[JULIA](https://julialang.org)
Some 55 bytes:

```
H(l,L=length.(l))=sort([(v,l[L.==v]) for v in Set(L)])
```

[Try](https://tio.run/##PU49a8MwEN31Kw5liAQi1AiPgkKhDcGBQkfjQcRKrKCejHwSSf68Ky9d3he8u3fPwdvmsa5HEVRngsMbTQcRpDRLTCR6UVTou4MxZZBwjQkKeIQfR6KTg2SMjZas6RlAzz/i6LjiXzFcK1kcK9bM420Tkw3bebdUc3Zk@aBqa5mDJ8HPTyg6PUE/LrppNBL8vtGkE9xzS9DqVPQIuQX0qGH2r9d7C7tTXshf3GdM3yFT5GoPe8kGxv53buPqkzl5pIDiKIqUzOG4rn8) it online

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 81 bytes

Outputs a dictionary instead of a list or tuple:

```
lambda s:dict(sorted((len(x),list(filter(lambda y:len(y)==len(x),s)))for x in s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCgMhDER/RTxF2FtvC556aH@h0ItbIytNjWig69fbFPYwbwiZmTpk53KZyT8nhc8Wg@lrzC@Bzk0wAhAWONxCuQukTIINzuBY/7/hvD8z3TmXuJnD5GL0mLXloi0Ae@WIdrE3pqR2RyJWf2BXBtWm@u5DyW9FZQnCVvfmDw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 53 bytes

```
{a=new map;a[#_]+=_1 if[a[#_1]?]else a[#_1]=[_1];[a]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BS8QwEIXP7a94sJcVPVhCL5aywoKisOC9lhK20240TUKSrnZrf3tNVrzMzPdm5s1Y3fJ14EJhThN0eCjxvs68VPSFgZuCV5umvi2bDKKrImT1ribpCH9QViEUFa@XNZnNKGWBGBf8oNMWQpnRo9VpkhgrlN9ehZuAPJ5yRop/LW5sY@eTJgce0HDr6EV56smiCYLT1kc9OiGM3YUnQqqvp0KRJq1WlC7rXreEZy07cNUikFA99icuJameHA7keXqYcGZ2Avs@sixjwXK49ydm8THmHjmzZ9ZizKGEYjDicnnMsXkdnRdHetL2TY5e/wI)

### Explanation

```
{a=new map;a[#_]+=_1 if[a[#_1]?]else a[#_1]=[_1];[a]}
{                                                   } anonymous function
 a=new map;                                           let a be a hash map
                                                      for each _1:
                     if[       ]else            ;     if
                        a[#_1]?                         a[length(_1)] exists
           a[#_]+=_1                                  then append _1 to a[length(_1)]
                                     a[#_1]=[_1]      else a[length(_1)] = [_1]
                                                 [a]  return a
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), chars 34, bytes 68

```
{a,⍨¨↑¨≢¨¨a←a⊂⍨≢¨a←a[⍋a←⍵⊂⍨' '≠⍵]}
```

test:

```
  f←{a,⍨¨↑¨≢¨¨a←a⊂⍨≢¨a←a[⍋a←⍵⊂⍨' '≠⍵]}
  ⎕fmt f 'Code Golf and coding challenges Meta'
┌4──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌2───────┐ ┌4────────────────────────┐ ┌2──────────┐ ┌2───────────────┐│
││  ┌3───┐│ │  ┌4────┐ ┌4────┐ ┌4────┐│ │  ┌6──────┐│ │   ┌10─────────┐││
││3 │ and││ │4 │ Code│ │ Golf│ │ Meta││ │6 │ coding││ │10 │ challenges│││
││~ └────┘2 │~ └─────┘ └─────┘ └─────┘2 │~ └───────┘2 │~~ └───────────┘2│
│└∊───────┘ └∊────────────────────────┘ └∊──────────┘ └∊───────────────┘3
└∊──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
  ⎕fmt f 'My v3ry 3xc13nt m0th3r 53rv3d u5 pzz@5 #Ju'
┌6─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌3────────────┐ ┌2───────┐ ┌2────────┐ ┌2─────────┐ ┌3────────────────────┐ ┌2───────────┐│
││  ┌2──┐ ┌2──┐│ │  ┌3───┐│ │  ┌4────┐│ │  ┌5─────┐│ │  ┌6──────┐ ┌6──────┐│ │  ┌7───────┐││
││2 │ My│ │ u5││ │3 │ #Ju││ │4 │ v3ry││ │5 │ pzz@5││ │6 │ 53rv3d│ │ m0th3r││ │7 │ 3xc13nt│││
││~ └───┘ └───┘2 │~ └────┘2 │~ └─────┘2 │~ └──────┘2 │~ └───────┘ └───────┘2 │~ └────────┘2│
│└∊────────────┘ └∊───────┘ └∊────────┘ └∊─────────┘ └∊────────────────────┘ └∊───────────┘3
└∊─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), <s>85</s> 94 bytes

**changed to to function format +9 bytes**

```lua
r={}m=0 for j=1,#i do w=i[j]l=#w m=l>m and l or m c=r[l]r[l]=c and w..","..c or w end return r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU@7isNADOz9FWLdxGBMzOJSx1UpDg7SGxdhbXMy@wjKbpxLyLf7Vr5CGs1IoBmbLtucvIkUPMwHqjbG19vhEebAsGBblwRjgBWpXwaL5QoO7YeDix/BQr5xYJB7O0ih2fW1aVStmsbIfoUpSzzFxB54y6QoeLolGwHzx5f6/lU1qLvmHfXD6LbVPgpxx/ijWaYldbvSab7rUabUSffkteCVns/PXSm/0i2SmU6BzzbFoN5VIVkoZ3ES5crk44HqfxM9DVX2tP0B)

Comment: Welcome to the site! The output format in this challenge is pretty loose so you could probably save some bytes if you move the print part to the footer in TIO.

Comment: Allright then, thanks for the hint. Im new to this so im learning :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
mṠ,oL←kL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fhzgU6@T6P2iZk@/z//z9ayTk/JVVJR8k9PycNSCXmpQBJoFhmXjqIkZGYk5Oal55aDOT4ppYkKsUCAA)

so close..

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 32 bytes

```arturo
$=>[gather arrange&=>size=>size]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?mAXF8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 64 bytes

```python
lambda x:{i:[*filter(lambda a:len(a)==i,x)]for i in range(1,11)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYwxDgIhEEWvQqjA0BA7EioLK0@wbjGGgZ0Ehw1S7MZ4dlyM1Xv/FX/d21L43KO/9wzPRwCxuTe56RQpN6zqH8FlZAXaezKbnmOpggSxqMAJlTXW6k9fK3FTUU3yUgJKI@S15DgIHAaOTJx@tkA@HhO@xrphAzlr3b8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 52 bytes

```sh
for i;printf \ $i>>$#i;(for j (*)<<<$j`<$j`)|sort -n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBDoIwEEbhPaf4E7poTTwBDSdhoRRHppUWW0II6tnHdPG@xTvLLKTNRyhlcLdmjhthgOK@Vy13un4PfTHWWuVvNfMtKW@4Rvk1hAN3jA7Tg/Cc2SO8loi04o1yuD346hgDToH8AQ)

For each argument/word `i`, append to a file called `$#i` (length of `i`). 
For each resulting file `j (*)`, print the filename `<<<$j` and contents `<$j`, and sort.